# My Mac osx, which is completely updated, turns off when I connect my Logitech mouse blue tooth thing to it

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, logitech-mouse

Essentially the title. I've had my Logitech mouse for a few years, it just recently, like two or three, maybe four days ago, started bugging out a bit. But it was handleable. But this morning while on my computer, it just turned off. The computer itself just shut down and I couldn't turn it on. After checking things a bit, I eventually decided to use my school computer, but before getting my computer out, I tried to turn it on again. After I disconnected the Logitech mouse. And it was on. So I was like "uhh that's weird" so I plugged the Logitech mouse thing back in and the computer shut down. any reason why it would do this?

Comment: So the "thingy" as I called it, is called a unifying receiver that connects the mouse and computer wirelessly. And testing it on my school computer, it works fine. More than fine, it works perfectly. So it's a Mac problem. Ffs macos always has problems...

Comment: Does connecting another USB device to the computer do the same thing? What about connecting the receiver to different ports on the computer?

Comment: it works the same no matter what port I put it in. I haven't tested other USB things yet,  and I'm too tired to do so right now. I'm like yawning, and can barely even cohesively string together thoughts clearly. I'll try when I get back from my cross-state trip tomorrow.